# How can Mongo store infinitely long comments in a blog post example

Tags: mongodb

Am looking to build a blogging system and came across the following blog.
http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/08/why-is-mongodb-wildly-popular/

While it's nice to see how we can store everything in one Mongo document as a json type object (example json from the blog pasted below) rather than distributing data across multiple tables, I'm having trouble understanding how this can accommodate an hypothetically super long comment thread.

```
{
    _id: 1234,
    author: { name: "Bob Davis", email : "bob@bob.com" },
    post: "In these troubled times I like to …",
    date: { $date: "2010-07-12 13:23UTC" },
    location: [ -121.2322, 42.1223222 ],
    rating: 2.2,
    comments: [
       { user: "jgs32@hotmail.com",
         upVotes: 22,
         downVotes: 14,
         text: "Great point! I agree" },
       { user: "holly.davidson@gmail.com",
         upVotes: 421,
         downVotes: 22,
         text: "You are a moron" }
    ],
    tags: [ "Politics", "Virginia" ]
 }
```

Aside from the comments key which is represented as an array of comment objects, allowing us to store an endless number of comments within this document rather than on a separate comments table requiring a join operation to relate if we are to do this with a relational database, the rest of the fields (ie author, post, date, location, rating, tags) can all be done as columns on a relational database table as well.

Since there is a limit of 16MB per document, what happens when this blog attracts a lot of comments?

Also, why can't I store a json object on a relational database column?  Afterall it's a text isn't it?

Comment: Who says one can't store json-text in e.g. a clob-column?

Comment: @DaniEll That's exactly what I meant.  We can store json in a relational database.  So what is the value of Mongo I'm getting?

Answer (score 1):

First, a clarification: MongoDB actually stores [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/), which is a essentially superset of JSON that supports more data types.

> Since there is a limit of 16MB per document, what happens when this blog attracts a lot of comments?

You won't be able to increase the size past 16MB, so you'll lose the ability to add more comments. But you don't need to store all the comments on the blog post document. You could store the first `N`, then retire old comments to a comments collection as new ones are added. You could store comments in another collection with a parent reference. The way comments are stored should jive with how you expect them to be used. 16MB of comments would really be a lot - you might even have a special solution to handle the occasional post that gets that kind of activity, an approach that's totally different from the normal way of handling comments.

> We can store json in a relational database. So what is the value of Mongo I'm getting?

Here's two ways of storing JSON (in MongoDB).

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "name" : { "first" : "Yogi", "last" : "Bear" }, "location" : "Yellowstone", "likes" : ["picnic baskets", "PBJ", "the great outdoors"] })
> db.test.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f9f41f245e945635f2137b"),
    "name" : {
        "first" : "Yogi",
        "last" : "Bear"
    },
    "location" : "Yellowstone",
    "likes" : [
        "picnic baskets",
        "PBJ",
        "the great outdoors"
    ]
}

var jsonstring = '{ "name" : { "first" : "Yogi", "last" : "Bear" }, "location" : "Yellowstone", "likes" : ["picnic baskets", "PBJ", "the great outdoors"] }'
> db.test.drop
> db.test2.insert({ "myjson" : jsonstring })
> db.test2.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f9f535245e945635f2137d"),
    "myjson" : "{ \"name\" : { \"first\" : \"Yogi\", \"last\" : \"Bear\" }, \"location\" : \"Yellowstone\", \"likes\" : [\"picnic baskets\", \"PBJ\", \"the great outdoors\"] }"
}
```

Can you store and use JSON the first way using a relational database? How useful is JSON stored in the second way compared to the first?

There's lots of other differences between MongoDB and relational databases that make one better than the other for various use cases - but going further into that is too broad for an SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you store and use JSON the first way using a relational database?
>   How useful is JSON stored in the second way compared to the first?

Sorry are you suggesting that with Mongo json documents can be stored without using escape characters, whereas with a RDBMS I must use escape characters to escape the double quotes?  I wasn't aware of that's the case.